# Horizontal ScrollView in fragment Android

Tags: android, scrollview, vertical-alignment

I would like to make my ScrollView filling out the full layout of a fragment and scrolling horizontally, not vertically.

How can I achieve that?!

[Like the album covers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxyJy.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Which Scrollview have you used? Can you share what you have done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not vertically, it is horizontally

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        // Add your ImageButtons
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: And if I put elements like ImageButtons in this LinearLayout now they will be scrolling vertically?

Comment: It just still scrolls horizontally and not vertically (left-to-right)

Comment: bro, vertically is up- down, horizontally is left-right. Which one do you need?

Comment: Check my updated answer. If it is your required answer please accept it.

Comment: Let me a second so I can try out, but it's most probably the right one!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the scrollview  to

```
    android:fillViewport="true"
```

Below is the complete code

```
 <ScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/myscrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
 </ScrollView>
```